# Ruby Gem: Get files in asset pipeline

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I've developed a plugin ( jQuery ) which I really want to make into a gem. For the gem to work I need three files to be in the asset pipeline of Rails: an image, a javascript file and a css file.

On this moment I've got the gem working, but! I can't get the files in the asset pipeline. If I include them like this:

```
//= require gem.js
```

Or

```
//= require gem.css
```

It works, but the files doesn't show up in the asset pipeline and while I can make this work with the css and js file, I can't make this work for the images.

Thereby I really want the files to show up in the asset pipeline ( or at least the image, which is needed to give the plugin extra glance ). On this moment I've done everything I could think off, but it doesn't work..

This is my gemspec:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
$:.push File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)
require "yellow-text-rails/version"

Gem::Specification.new do |gem|
    # Gem information
    gem.name          = "yellow-text-rails"
    gem.version       = YellowText::Rails::VERSION
    gem.authors       = ["Stefan Vermaas"]

    # Project name
    gem.rubyforge_project = "yellow-text-rails" 

    gem.files         = `git ls-files`.split("\n")
    gem.test_files    = `git ls-files -- {test,spec,features}/*`.split("\n")
    gem.executables   = `git ls-files -- bin/*`.split("\n").map{ |f| File.basename(f) }
    gem.require_paths = ["lib"]
end
```

And I've included this in `lib/yellow-text-rails/yellow-text-rails.rb':

```
require "yellow-text-rails/version"

module YellowText
    module Rails
        if defined?(::Rails) and ::Rails.version >= "3.1"
                class Rails::Engine < ::Rails::Engine
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Hopefully you guys can help me out! Thanks!

Comment: Using a sass image-helper in my .scss file did work. The images we're available in the asset pipeline, but not visible in the file tree. Still want to make the images and files visible, but can't find a solution..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
module YellowText
  module Rails
    class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
      initializer :append_dependent_assets_path, group: :all do |app|
        app.config.assets.precompile += %w( gem.js gem.css )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Make sure to include your assets in these folders in your gem `vendor/assets/javascripts` and `vendor/assets/stylesheets`.

Have a look at one of my simple Gems for reference: https://github.com/wazery/vider